# how to create an index for a IN usage in two columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

I need to optimize a table (It's INNODB) where I'm going to do a query using `IN` in two columns.

This is the query:

```
SELECT `emails`.* FROM `emails` 
  WHERE (`from` IN ('some@email.com', 'other@email.com') OR `to` IN ('some@email.com', 'other@email.com'))
```

the `from` and `to` fields are `VARCHAR(255)`

How I can create an index to help speed it up. Or if I should change my query strategy please let me know

I'm not sure if I should create one index for each column, or a single index with the two columns. I'm also not sure if the `IN` clause will make the index work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### question 1 - which index to create

Just create one index for each column.
After that mysql would be able combine results of each index into one set.
[More](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html) on the subject

#### question 2 - in clauses

You can check it out yourself via `explain` after you create the indexes. It should work. If for some reason your mysql version doesn't use the index for `IN` queries, you can rewrite your original query using `OR` because your query is equivalent to

```
`from` = 'some@email.com' OR `from` = 'other@email.com' OR `to` =  'some@email.com' OR `to` = 'other@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case "index merge" does not kick in, "turn OR into UNION":

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `emails`
    WHERE  `from` IN ('some@email.com', 'other@email.com')
UNION
SELECT  *
    FROM  `emails`
    WHERE  `from``to` IN ('some@email.com', 'other@email.com')
```

And have

```
INDEX(`from`),
INDEX(`to`)
```